# Kerberos SSH Login

Tags: networking, server, ssh, kerberos

I'm trying to setup a

- ssh server
- ssh client
- kerberos server

Now, on both the SSH server and client I can poll a ticket by calling, `kinit -p root/admin`.

In SSH/SSHD config I set

- `GSSAPIAuthentication yes`
- `GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes`
- `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes`

Now when I try from client to ssh to the ssh-server I'm still prompted about password, why is that?

```
$ ssh -vv sshserver
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: 
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
SHA256:71jU1n0c5M2uGF1RA37xc5ktz7CVmq2lqztrM+0ApX8
debug1: Host 'sshserver.kea.dk' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ghost/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_rsa (0x564e5774b270)
debug2: key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 
SHA256:V731Bh8CcX3x80tGJcwqsSBOo0wZbq2iIFc+ZHnyadg
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ghost/.ssh/id_ed25519
 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Did you add a service principal for sshd to your kerberos database?

Comment: I think I did when I made the key for the ssh server?
When doing listprincs it shows ssh/mykerberos.kea.dk@MYKERBEROS.KEA.DK

Comment: Are you using the exact same hostname for the ssh command line like shown in listprincs? That would have to be "ssh mykerberos.kea.dk"